# Adjust the microphone input volume

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, calibration

I'm developing an iOS 4 application for iPhone.

I want to use mic on my app, and I'm following this [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) to get mic input values. I'm not using any filter.

My problem is that I can't use my app propertly when there is a noise (not so much).

Is there any way to calibrate iPhone's mic? On my mac system preferences -> sound -> input; there is an utility to do this.

How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial code contains a decision threshold (of 0.95).  Assuming the mic isn't overloaded and clipping, if you change the average peak threshold up, this will be equivalent to turning the input volume down.